# The specified type member 'UsersCount' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6.1

I have such POCO entity

```
  public class Product : Entity

 {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }              
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int UsersCount
        {
            get
            {
                return  Orders.Count(); 
            }
        }

}
```

Product access method

```
 public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Product.Include(I=>I.Orders);          
        }
```

When I load all products into View

```
      var model = _productService.GetAll().Select(p => new AdminProductViewModel
        {
            Active = p.Active,
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            UsersCount = p.UsersCount
        }).ToList();
```

I get exception

> The specified type member 'UsersCount' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

I really can't understand why Linq to Entity gives exception. Maybe someone explain what is wrong?

We also use calculated fields in another application like this

```
 public class User : Entity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }               
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool Active
        {
            get
            {
                return Orders.Any(c => c.Active && (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order || c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription));
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public int CreditsLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return Orders.Where(w => w.Active).Sum(p => p.Credits != null ? p.Credits.Value : 0);
            }
        }
}

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    }

var user = _userService.Get(_authUser.Id);

 var model = new UserViewModel
            {
                Active = user.Active,
                FullName = user.FullName,
                Email = user.Email,
            };
```

and have no problems, EF6 don't give any exception though it also has two calculated fields `User.Active` and `User.CreditsLeft`

Comment: See the rest of the exception message. That tells you what's going on.

Comment: "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." And what? UsersCount contain linq-to-Entity supported code Orders.Count(); 
Exception text do not gives me logical explanation why I get exception. I do not use any code which can't be translated to actual SQL.

Comment: Yes you do, although it may not seem obvious. EF only sees `UsersCount` and tries to translate *that* into SQL. It doesn't *inspect* members it encounters in LINQ queries. Moreover, `UsersCount` is not mapped, so if EF *could* map it to a SQL column or function you didn't allow it to. You'll have to write `Orders.Count()` directly in the LINQ statement.

Comment: I have posted new code from our other application, it has calculated and fields are not mapped to database and everything works fine. Maybe you could give me idea why in same cases it works and sometimes id don't.

Comment: There the other data are evaluated when the user is in memory, not when it is fetched from the database.

Comment: @GertArnold Add your comments as the answer, I'll upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that LINQ to Entities tries to translate each LINQ statement into SQL. Your statement...

```
var model = _productService.GetAll().Select(p => new AdminProductViewModel...
```

...is a LINQ extension method (`Select`) against an `IQueryable` (`_productService.GetAll()`). As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548743%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows, this method takes an `Expression` as argument.

You can see an expression as a tree of tokens that *express* the task it should execute. A LINQ provider, simply said, is a dictionary of tokens in "expression language" to tokens in some other language, SQL in this case. The whole statement is translated into SQL and executed by the database. The .Net runtime only sends the statement away and processes the returned result.

Inspecting EF's source code reveals that many tokens are hard-coded: all SQL keywords, a number of built-in ("canonical") functions (like `DATEDIFF`) and a selection of .Net methods. Other tokens are added by mapping entity properties to database columns. Recently, `ToString()` was added to the .Net part of the dictionary. In EF6 we can write...

```
_context.Product.Select(p => p.Id.ToString())
```

Before that, this would raise the infamous

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'

Your exception has the same cause, but it pertains to members in stead of methods. `p.UsersCount` is not in the dictionary because it is not mapped.

> We also use calculated fields in another application like this

Here a `User` has been fetched from the database and materialized as a C# object. Now when you access its properties it's just .Net code running. There's no SQL translation going on here. Well... it probably triggers lazy loading (of orders and credits), but the act of *accessing* the property does not happen in the context of an expression.

Likewise, you can access `UsersCount` once you've got a `Product` object. If you want the database to do the heavy lifting of counting the orders, you'll have to use the expression in the LINQ statement:

```
var model = _productService.GetAll().Select(p => new AdminProductViewModel
    {
        Active = p.Active,
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        UsersCount = p.Orders.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
   var model = _productService.GetAll().Select(p => new AdminProductViewModel
   {
      Active = p.Active,
      Id = p.Id,
      Name = p.Name,
      UsersCount = p.Orders.Count()
   }).ToList();
```

Linq to Entities can't translate the `Product.UsersCount` property into sql so it gives you the error message

> The specified type member 'UsersCount' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities