# EF6 using custom property in a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a class which has the following property:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Key
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}_{1}", Process.Name, LocalSequenceNumber);
    }
}
```

The local sequence number is a computed integer backed by a cache in form of a concurrent dictionary.

I wish to use the Key property above in a LINQ query but get the exception:

> The specified type member 'Key' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I understand why I'm getting this error, but I'm not too sure about how to remedy it. Currently, the Key property is providing a nice encapsulation over my class which I don't want to part with. Any suggestions in terms of libraries, or simple patterns to get around this?

Edit: Here's the query which is throwing the exception:

```
db.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && c.Key == key);
```

Comment: Without **the code** that's actually throwing the exception, it's pretty hard to say why.

Comment: i've added the query.

Comment: Well you told EF not to map Key to a database column, then you want to use it in a query.  Not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: Remember that LINQ to Entities translates the statement into SQL, if you use `NotMappedAttribute` then the property can't be translated into SQL statement.

Comment: Right I've already made that clear and I understand the problem. It's a computed property which I would like to use as part of a query. My question is if there's a way around this.

Comment: A computed property should be using `Select` to project it into the model class. Read similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867470/the-specified-type-member-userscount-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities.

Comment: @Riz: though it sounds like an overdo but can you map your entity to a model class using something like AutoMapper and then try this query?

Comment: good point Tetsuya. Thanks for your helpful comment. I am now calling .ToList() to first materialize my list based on the first part of the query, and then querying it on the computed property and it works like a charm. If you post your response in an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 4):

The DelegateDecompiler package https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler handles this type of scenario.

Decorate your property with the `Computed` attribute, then queries like the following should work if you add the `Decompile` method:

```
db.Cars.Decompile().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && c.Key == key)
```

Comment: I've been using EF ever since 1.0 came out in 2007 (and Linq2Sql before that) and I can't believe I didn't know about `DelegateDecompiler` until now - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous third party packages that can solve this problem. I also believe that there are methods in EF.Core that can help, however, I will suggest 2 "pure Entity Framework 6" solutions.

1. Execute your query in two parts - the SQL part, then the "in code" part.

`db.Cars.Where(c => c.Id == id).ToList().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Key == key)`

this will still keep your logic encapsulated in the class, but you do not get the benefit of the SQL execution.

2. What I like to call the "projector" pattern. This one is a bit more long-winded.

Essentially, you create a "view" of the EF POCO that represents a data-transfer-object. it has the properties you need for your view, and also determines how to project the data from the database to the view.

```
// Poco:
public class Car {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string LocalSequenceNumber {get;set;}
  public int ProcessId {get;set; }
  public virtual Process Process {get;set;}
  // ...
}
public class Process {
 // ...
}

// View+Projector:
public class CarView
{ 
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Color {get;set;}
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public static Expression<Func<Car, CarView>> Projector = car => new CarView {
    Id = car.Id,
    Color = car.Color,
    Key = car.Process.Name + " " + car.LocalSequenceNumber 
  }
}

// calling code
var car = db.Cars.Select(CarView.Project).SingleOrDefault(cv => cv.Id == id && cv.Key == key)
```

This will evaluate all code on the database, whilst encapsulating your business logic in code.

Comment: Yep the simplest approach is 1 where the .ToList() executes the deferred query and receives the results "off" server and then the Linq `.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Key == key)` is just run over the in memory IEnumerable and isn't trying to execute via LinqToEntities.

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to tell us what `Process.Name` and `LocalSequenceNumber` are. From the identifiers it seems that they are not part of your `Cars`, but values in your local process. Why not calculate the Key before your query?

```
var key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", Process.Name, LocalSequenceNumber);
db.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && c.Key == key);
```

If, on the other hand, `Process.Name` or `LocalSequenceNumber` are `Car` properties, you'll have to change the `IQueryable.Expression` that is in your LINQ query using only properties and methods that can be translated by your `IQueryable.Provider` into SQL.

Luckily, your `Provider` knows `ToSTring()` and the concept of string concatenation So you can use that

As you are using property `Key` in a `Queryable.Where`, I suggest extending `IQueryable` with a function `WhereKey`. If extension functions are a bit magic for you, see [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IQueryable<Car> WhereKey(this IQueryable<Car> cars, int id, string key)
{
    return cars.Where(car => car.Id == id
            && key == car.Process.Name.ToString() + "_" + car.LocalSequenceNumber.ToString());
}
```

Usage:

```
int carId = ...
string carKey = ...
var result = myDbContext.Cars
    .WhereKey(carId, carKey)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Consider creating a `WhereKey` that only checks the key. The concatenate with a `Where` that selects on `Id`.

```
 var result = myDbContext.Cars
    .Where(car => car.Id == id)
    .WhereKey(carKey)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If either `Process.Name` or `LocalSequenceNumber` is not a part of Car, add it as a parameter. You get the gist.

Consider creating a `WhereKey` that only checks the key. The concatenate with a `Where` that selects on `Id`.

If desired, you can create a `WhereKeyFirstOrDefault()`, but I doubt whether this would be of much use.